# Can't launch debugger for Visual Studio Extension

Tags: themes, vscode-debugger

I'm using this LinkedIn learning course https://www.linkedin.com/learning/visual-studio-code-building-an-extension/scaffolding-an-extension?u=67553434 to create an Extension. I'm creating a theme currently, so its a .json file

The course tells me to launch the debugger, but I keep getting an error saying "Cannot launch program (file path); setting the 'outFiles' attribute might help. Any idea what this means? is my file path correct?

I'm sure i'm doing something silly, so would appreciate any quick help to get me going. Thanks!

[image: Error message in laucnh program json file]

[image: File path for my extension]

Comment: I don't really know whats going on but I just copied and pasted some code from an older extension I was working on. This is what I used to be able to launch my debugger

Comment: `{
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "configurations": [
  {
   "name": "Launch Extension",
   "type": "extensionHost",
   "request": "launch",
   "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
   "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}" ],
   "stopOnEntry": false
  },
  {
   "name": "Launch Tests",
   "type": "extensionHost",
   "request": "launch",
   "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
   "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}", "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceRoot}/test" ],
   "stopOnEntry": false
  }
 ]
}`